# still confused about conics

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

Hello I have tried to post a few questions to try to understand better some things in conics. I am still really confused and am looking for help to understand.  I am especially confused about graphing conics and the relation between the directrix and eccentricity. Maybe the best way for me to explain is give the examples of some of the questions asked and show what I have tried and what I am confused about.

One of the questions says given a focus of (5,0) and a directrix of x=0 draw a conic with eccentricity of , then it gives a few options

1) 0.2

For this I just used that $\frac{PF}{PD}=\frac{1}{5}$ so $5PF=PD$
 My thoughts are this is an ellipse.

But I dont know where to go from here, if I were to say x is the distance from the directrix to the left vertex that I could say $PD=x$ then $PF=x/5$ for example but I dont know.

2) 0.8

also an ellipse and similar to above but $\frac{PF}{PD}=\frac{4}{5}$ instead. But I dont know how I can find points of these?

3) 1

I know this is supposed to be a parabola. With bassicaly just PF=PD , is that all I can say? How could I actually find a point? How can I find the origin?

4) 5

$$\frac{PF}{PD}=5$$

I know this is supposed to be a Hyperbola with $PF=5PD$ but after that im lost.

I really hope someone can take the time to help me understand. Thanks a lot for anyone who can help

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

For $X=(x,y)$

> the equation of the conic is $ \overline {XF} = e \overline {Xd} \qquad (1)$

where:

$e$ is the eccentricity, $\overline {XF}$ is the distance from the focus, that in your case is $\sqrt{(x-5)^2+y^2}$ and $\overline {Xd}$ is the distance from the directix, that in your case is $|x|$. ([see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#Eccentricity.2C_focus_and_directrix)).

Write the equation $(1)$ for the differnt eccentricities , square (and reorder), and you have the equations of the conics.

As examples:

for $e=\frac{1}{5}$ ( your case 1 ), you find the equation:

$$
(x-5)^2+y^2=\dfrac{1}{25}x^2
$$
Can you show that this is an ellipse?

For $e=1$ ( case 3) the equation is:
$$
(x-5)^2+y^2=x^2
$$
That is a parabola.

... and so one on the other cases...

Comment: You are reffering to example (1)? And that equation holds for all conic sections?

Comment: I'm referring to $ \overline {XF} = e \overline {Xd} \qquad (1)$ and, yes, this equation holds for all conics.

Comment: Thank you, I mean when you say in your case, but I put a few cases

Comment: This works in all your cases, simply use the value of the eccentricity $e$ that you want.

Comment: @Quality: I've added to my answer. I hope it's usefull ;)

Comment: Thank you I am waiting untill I am have time to work through later on tonight and then i will accept and maybe might have a few last couple question

Comment: When e<1 you get an ellipse.When e=1 tou get a parabola.When e>1 you get a hyperbola.